# How much data is ok to put in the global $user object or $_SESSION variables?

Tags: 7, users

I'm building a site and there are some pieces of information that I am going to use constantly.  My thinking is that instead of making a ton of database calls, that I would put some of these critical pieces of info in the $user object or $_SESSION variables.  The question is, however, how much is too much info in these variables?  Which should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to put a limit on things like this. But if you have more than a few pieces of data related to the user, you should probably put it in a table of it own. You can add the data to the user when loaded, and the performance hit will only be a few ms, not measurable really. You will make things easier on yourself by being able to query the data instead of having it stored as serialized data.

One thing to note about `$_SESSION` is that it should only be used for storing temporary data. A use case could be storing the values entered in a form, to let the user pick up from where he left, if he moves away from the form and comes back later.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a drupal way of dealing with global data. But if you want to go this way you are limited only by the memory available for your php script which is set in the `php.ini` under the `memory-limit` variable. Normally it would be set to 16-32MB but of course if you are able to modify the `php.ini` settings you could make it higher.