# Is it okay to store a $node object as a $_SESSION variable

Tags: 7, sessions

My contrib module currently stores a `$node` object temporarily in the `variable` table, and stores the `nid` for that `$node` in the `$_SESSION` variable so that the `$node` can be retrieved from the variable table at a later point.

Would it be okay to store the `$node` directly in the `$_SESSION` variable? Or would there perhaps be a performance of security impact?

If it is okay to store a $node object in the `$_SESSION` variable, do I need to serialize it first?

Comment: What is the szenario? Why can't you store the nid in the session and load the node again when you need it?

Comment: Good question! My module (http://drupal.org/project/csm) sometimes does stuff with $node when it hasn't been saved to the database, so I have to temporarily store the node somewhere else so the module can access various parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the ctools object cache API here, this is what views uses to store edits to a view until they are saved and is what Drupal 8 uses for node preview. In D8 it's called user temp store.

Comment: Cool, so the relevant API is in D8 core? I suspect that including ctools as a dependancy for my module is no the way to go, as my module is pretty tiny and ctools is a lot of code, but will definitely consider using anything that's in core when I do the D8 port.

Comment: Well views requires ctools, so most sites have it already. But yeah the API is in core in D8, node preview is a good example to check

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns and this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7492/how-much-data-is-ok-to-put-in-the-global-user-object-or-session-variables?rq=1) point toward no, storing objects in session is bad practice for security and performance. If you dont want to create your own table to track these items, you can also use the `data` field in the user table/object. This data is also serialized.

However, as your question is written, "yes" you "can" store nodes in $_SESSION... php/drupal will allow it. But as mentioned, this is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have any concerns per se; I'm just not sure about whether I should have concerns! I think for now I'll keep doing what I've been doing to this point (storing $node in the variable table) and storing the nid in $_SESSION.